# MRUnit with HBase and MapReduce gets an error with serialization

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, mrunit

I'm trying to test my MapReduce with MRUnit, when I do the integration test, it works. I have some unit test that I want to pass them as well.

My MRUnit driver and MapReduce class are:

```
MapDriver<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result, ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>

public final class HashMapper extends
    TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>
```

When I define the input I get an error:

```
mapDriver.withInput(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes
                .toBytes("query")), new Result(kvs1));

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.output.MockOutputCollector.collect(MockOutputCollector.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.mapreduce.AbstractMockContextWrapper$4.answer(AbstractMockContextWrapper.java:90)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocationMatcher.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockHandler.handle(MockHandler.java:95)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:47)
```

I guess that it's because it doesn't like the Result and KeyValue object since they're not Writable, but I don't undersntad why the integration tests works then. It was working before with Hbase 0.94 when all these objects implement Writable, now I'm working with HBase 0.96. Any clue how should I use MRUnit here?

Answer (score 2):

With the version HBase 0.96 some classes aren't implement Writable anymore, but people from HBase have created a new serialize classes for them.

So, the solutions is to indicate in the Configuration what classes MRUnit must use:

The property is called **io.serializations**
The different serializes are:

Result class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ResultSerialization
KeyValue class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.KeyValueSerialization
Put & Get classes org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MutationSerialization

Comment: +1 But I don't think there is serialization implemented for Put and Get.  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ResultSerialization implemnts Result class and org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.KeyValueSerialization implements KeyValue

Comment: Ignore the above comment the formatting confused me. Later, I realized you mean to tell MutationSerialization implements serialization for Put/Get